# Regular expressions for getting all kinds of tokens including hyphens

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, split, nlp

I want to split a sentence into words and special characters. I am using the regular expression below:

```
@"((\b[^\s]+\b)((?<=\.\w).)?)
```

But it returns only words and not special characters such as space-separated hyphens or colons.

Ideally, for the sentence:

> "Right now!" she shouted, and hands fluttered in the air - amid a few cheers - for 
>   about two minutes.

I should get:

```
Right
now
she
shouted
and
hands
fluttered
in
the
air
-
amid
a
few
cheers
-
for
about
two
minutes
```

Comment: No only individual tokens, no charachters which are directly attached to a word.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [this regex](http://www.regex101.com/r/cB9vS6) will do what you're looking for:

```
@"\b\s?([A-Za-z-]+)\s?\b"
```

Seems a bit too simple for the regex you've been trying though! Is there something more perhaps?

Comment: This is a match by the way! Casimir's split regex seems to do the trick (haven't tested it), though I would put a caret at the start so as not to get the first quote `(?:\s+|^)(?:\p{P}(?!\s))?|\b\p{P}+\s*`.

Comment: Actually, @"\b\s?[A-Za-z-]+\s?\b" also renders a space after some words (in the above example, after every word except 'now', 'shouted', 'air', 'cheers' and 'minutes'). How to avoid that?

Comment: It also doesn't give me colons and other space separated charachters.

Comment: @aceBox Do you mean that if you have `This is a sentence: not a phrase.`, you should get `This`, `is`, `a`, `sentence`, `:`, `not`, `a`, `phrase`? (And for some reason, I forgot to put the brackets in my answer while I have put them in the link, which prevents the capture of spaces. Oops, fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps splitting with a pattern like this:

```
@"\s+(?:\p{P}(?!\s))?|\b\p{P}+\s*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want a non-regex way to remove punctuation from sentence and still keep the hypen:

```
import string
s = '"Right now!" she shouted, and hands fluttered in the air - amid a few cheers - for about two minutes.'
x = "".join([c for c in s if c =="-" or c not in string.punctuation])
```

Outputs:

```
'Right now she shouted and hands fluttered in the air - amid a few cheers - for about two minutes'
```

Simply use `x.split()` to get it tokenized to your desired output.